# Force pushing to new head when already pulled all changes

Tags: mercurial, branch, push, dvcs

Is it possible to forcibly create new remote head when pushing ?

Suppose I have done some local commits on branch "default" then pulled and merged from remote.

Now, I would like to push my commits to remote creating new head and a bookmark but preserve existing remote head and tip - ie. my coworkers should not get my changes yet when doing `hg fetch`.

Basically this should be a short lived branch (thus not a named branch) for purpose of backup and code review by other before being fully merged into "main" head of default branch.

I've tried `--new-branch` but it didn't help - no new head was created and remote tip moved to my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--force` option to force the creation of a new head.

The `--new-branch` option is used for named branch, in your case, we are talking of anonymous branching.

The reason why the "tip is moved" is because you merged the changeset recently pulled. Doing that, there's no way to do what you want.

You should just pull the new changes from the remote, and force push everything without merging, this will create a new head (called an anonymous branch), which can later be merged to the default branch by you or someone else after the code review.

You can also use a second repository to push your changes, but this is a totally different workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** preserve `tip` when you push: it is a pseudo-tag that **always** points to the newest changeset in a repository. The concept of `tip` is deprecated in Mercurial because `tip` can change meaning more or less randomly depending on the order of pushes — as you've seen.

The only way to create a new head is to, well, create it :-) By this I mean that you **need** two heads — one with your changes and one with the main code you want the colleges to pull and merge with. With only a single head (the one you got after running `hg merge`) there's no way to signal to the colleges that they shouldn't use it.

A much **better approach** is to use a **separate** repository on the server. Go to your repository management software and create a fork for your changes. Then push into that and tell your colleges to review it. They'll pull from your clone and look the changes over. If they like them, then they can merge with the main code and push to the normal repo. If they don't like the changes, then they can throw away their local clone, strip the changesets, or maybe just rollback the pull.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this issue is to use a previous revision for the start of the bookmark, if there is none or you just do not want to, you can make a dummy commit (like a small change to a README file, etc.) and bookmark the revision before that.

I think hg bookmarks need a lot of fine tuning before they become like git branches, but the process I describe is pretty much what is explained in the [mercurial bookmarks kick starter](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/bookmarks/).

For example, if your currently at revision 250.

```
echo >>README
hg ci -m "enabling bookmark branch_xyz"
hg book my-tip # optional but nice to have
hg book -r 250 branch_xyz
hg up branch_xyz
# hack ... hack hack
hg ci -m "awesome feature xyz (in progress)"
hg push -fB branch_xyz
```

## now this bookmark lives on the server for others to work with ... but can be easily pruned later

Comment: I agree the Bookmark atleast in tools like Eclipse needs some TLC. Its really annoying when you have multiple heads with bookmarks and Eclipse asks on every update if you want to merge.